# About comaximal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I was thinking about this the other day, say we have three comaximal ideal, $I,J,K$ in a commutative ring. (this means that $I+J=J+K=K+I=R$), does it have to follow that $I+JK=R$?

I was trying to argue that if $I+JK\neq R$ then there is a maximal ideal $M$ containing it, so it also contains $I$, if I manage to show that $M$ contains $K$ or $J$ then I would be done since it would contain their sum, but it would contradict the maximality assumption.

So far I haven't done it (and it might also be false, its just something I wondered when I was reading)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your start is OK:

A maximal ideal containing $I+JK$ would be a prime ideal containing $JK$ and $I$, and so one of $J$ or $K$ are contained in the maximal ideal. Can you see why this spells a contradiction?

Comment: I dont see how we get $JK\subset M$ then $J\subset M$ or $K\subset M$. Primality of $M$ gives us that for elements, but how does it follow for actual ideals?

Comment: Like a priori I could have $j_1k_1\in M$ and $k_1\in M$ and $i_1\notin M$ and $i_2k_2\in M$ with $i_2\in M$ and $k_2\notin M$.

Comment: @DanielMontealegre The property *is* true for prime ideals. Suppose $JK\subseteq M$ and $J\not\subseteq M$; then there is $a\in J$, $a\notin M$. Now take $b\in K$ and do $ab$; what can you say?

Comment: @egreg thanks!!

Comment: @DanielMontealegre The "ideal-wise" definition of primeness generalizes the "element-wise" definition to noncommutative rings. Thanks, egreg, for helping explain that :)